Proof of Beppo Levi's Theorem
I am self-studying measure theory using Measure Theory by Donald Cohn. The text presented the following result but lack of detailed proof. I tried to write up the proof, and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me check if it is correct and rigorous.
Here is the result:

Beppo Levi's Theorem$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite series whose terms are $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$. Then
\begin{align*}
    \int\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_kd\mu = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int f_kd\mu.
\end{align*}

Here is my attempt:

Proof$\quad$ Let $g_n=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)$ and $g=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$. By Proposition 2.1.5 and 2.1.6 below, $g_n$'s and $g$ are $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. Since each $f_k$ is $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, it follows that the sequence $\{g_n\}$ is an increasing sequence, so that $\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)\to\alpha\in[0,+\infty]$ for all $x$ in $X$. Denote $\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x) = \alpha = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
g_1(x) \leq g_2(x) \leq \dots
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)
\end{align*}
hold at every $x$ in $X$. Therefore, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem (see below), we have
\begin{align*}
\int\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_kd\mu = \int gd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int g_nd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_kd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\int f_kd\mu,\tag1
\end{align*}
where the last equality holds because of the linearity of the integral. Since $f_k$ is $[0,+\infty]$-valued, then $\int f_kd\mu = \sup\left\{\int gd\mu:g\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ g\leq f_k\right\}$ must be $[0,+\infty]$-valued, and so $\sum_{k=1}^n\int f_kd\mu$ is $[0,+\infty]$-valued as well. Thus, $\sum_{k=1}^n\int f_kd\mu \to \lambda \in [0,+\infty]$. Denote $\lambda=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int f_kd\mu$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\int f_kd\mu = \lambda = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int f_kd\mu$. Therefore, equality (1) implies
\begin{align*}
\int\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_kd\mu = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int f_kd\mu.
\end{align*}

Thanks a lot in advance!

Results used in my proof:

Proposition 2.1.5$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space, let $A$ be a subset of $X$ that belongs to $\mathcal{A}$, and let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of $[-\infty,+\infty]$-valued measurable functions on $A$. Then the function $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ (whose domain is $\{x\in A:\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\}$) is measurable.


Proposition 2.1.6$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space, let $A$ be a subset of $X$ that belongs to $\mathcal{A}$, let $f$ and $g$ be $[0,+\infty]$-valued measurable functions on $A$, and let $\alpha$ be a nonnegative real number. Then $\alpha f$ and $f+g$ are measurable.


Theorem 2.4.1$\quad$ The Monotone Convergence Theorem$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots,$ be $[0,\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$. Suppose that
\begin{align}
    f_1(x) \leq f_2(x) \leq \dots
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
    f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)
\end{align}
hold at $\mu$-almost every $x$ in $X$. Then $\int fd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_nd\mu$.


The theorem of Beppo Levi is the Theorem of Monotone Convergence. In your case just in a format using a sum instead of a sequence. Totally trivial.
